# Listing Entries from Table1 which do not appear in Table 2

Tags: mariadb, join, query

Currently I am working with 2 tables... one table consists of jobs carried out and also the invoice number... there could be multiple jobs for a customer on the one invoice... the table might look like

| customer | job | invoiceNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer 1 | JobA | 123 |
| Customer 1 | JobA | 123 |
| Customer 1 | JobA | 124 |
| Customer 1 | JobA | 124 |
| Customer 2 | JobA | 125 |
| Customer 2 | JobA | 125 |
| Customer 2 | JobA | 125 |
| Customer 3 | JobA | 126 |

I then run a query to group by invoice number

`SELECT * from Table1 Group BY InvoiceNo`

Resulting in

| customer | job | invoiceNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer 1 | JobA | 123 |
| Customer 1 | JobA | 124 |
| Customer 2 | JobA | 125 |
| Customer 3 | JobA | 126 |

Table 2 looks like:

| customer | invoiceNo | link |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer 1 | 123 | https://www.invoice.com/1 |
| Customer 1 | 124 | https://www.invoice.com/2 |

Basically what I want to do is run a query to find the invoice numbers from table 1 which do not appear in table 2.
Although I would like to take this one step further...

I have a dropdown list with all of my customers. Ideally I wold like to select a customer from the dropdown which will then run the `query which I am looking for` to populate the next drop down with the invoices frim table 1 which do not currently have a link

Something like

```
SELECT * From Table1
WHERE customer = (dropdownSelection) AND (invoiceNo doesn not appear on Table2)
```

I hope I have explained this well enough
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: *I then run a query to group by invoice number ```SELECT * from Table1 Group BY InvoiceNo```* This query is incorrect. Incomplete grouping. You'd run ```SELECT DISTINCT * from Table1;```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you just want a `NOT EXISTS`, and a parameter for `customer`

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 AS t1
WHERE customer = ?
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM Table2 AS t2
    WHERE T2.invoiceNo = T1.invoiceNo
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had an idea that `Not Exists` might be required but I have never used it and wasnt entirely sure how to. Your answer looks a lot easier than I was expecting but it works!

Is there anything I could add to the above to ensure that `null` values are not displayed?

I have tried adding `WHERE customer = ? AND invoiceNo IS NOT NULL` and also `WHERE customer = ? AND invoiceNo != NULL` but neither work. the First gives an error and the latter returns no results

Comment: I got it... `WHERE customer = ? AND invoiceNo IS NOT NULL` worked, The software I was using to run the query uses prepared statemements and `IS` does not work when using prepared statements, turned this function off and it works fine :)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: @PaulMcF87 You may also use `SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 USING (invoiceNo) WHERE t2.invoiceNo IS NULL;`. Add condition by `customer` if needed.

Comment: @Akina `DISTINCT` is unnecessary, and likely going to cause performance problems. `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` is semantically the same but usually performs worse (at least on any decent DBMS).

Comment: @Charlieface You're correct. I went from WHERE EXISTS and forget to remove DISTINCT.